# A polynomial that is reducible under every finite field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

Q: Prove that for any finite field $\mathbb{F_q}$, the ring $\mathbb{F_q}[x]/(x^9+x^5+x^3+x+1)$ cannot be a field.

Upon first glance I am really not sure where to start. Intuitively, it seems that I should be finding a way to show that $x^9+x^5+x^3+x+1$ is reducible over every finite field.

I have that:
$x^9+x^5+x^3+x+1 = (x^2-x+1)(x^7+x^6-x^4+x^2+2x+1)$ but I don't see where to go from here.

Am I even on the right track? Is there some well-known theorem I've blanked on that would help me out? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You just factored it over $\mathbb{Z}$. You are done. If it's reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ then it's reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for every prime $p$.

Comment: @EthanAlwaise: well, one must be a little careful: $3X^{2}+X$ is reducible as $X(3X+1)$ over $\mathbb{Z}$, but is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_{3}$. But since both of the factors in the product above are monic, there are no issues of this kind.

Comment: Ah right, good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*From the comments above.*

---

If $f(x) = x^9 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, then you have shown that $f = gh$, where $g(x) = x^2 - x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $h(x) = x^7 + x^6 - x^4 + x^2 + 2x + 1 \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$. Let $p$ be a prime and $\bar{f}$, $\bar{g}$ and $\bar{h}$ denote the images of $f$, $g$ and $h$, respectively, under the canonical map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{F}_p$. Then, $\bar{f} = \bar{g} \bar{h}$ and $\bar{g}$ and $\bar{h}$ are nonconstant polynomials in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. Hence, $\bar{f}$ is irreducible over every finite field, as was needed to be shown.